# Docker composeとは何ですか？

Tags: docker, docker-compose

そもそもDocker composeってなんですか？分かりやすく教えてください。後これはチーム開発に必要なんですか？

Answer (score 3):

Docker Compose は、特に複数の Docker コンテナが協調して動くようなアプリケーションを取り扱いやすくするツールです。Docker Compose 用の設定ファイルを書いておくことで、コマンドひとつで複数のコンテナがそれぞれの設定込みで一斉に立ち上がり、アプリケーションとして動かせるようになります。

たとえばお手元の開発環境で Web アプリやそのアプリが参照するデータベースを、開発環境にある他のアプリの影響を受けづらい隔離された環境で起動させつつ動作検証をしたくなることがあります。このとき Web アプリとデータベースをそれぞれコンテナとして起動させつつ、Web アプリのコンテナからデータベースのコンテナを参照して通信させたくなるでしょう。それぞれのコンテナをひとつずつ手動で起動するのは面倒ですし、コンテナ間の通信設定を毎回書くのも面倒です。これらをひとつの設定ファイルにあらかじめ書いておくことで、あとは Docker Compose を起動すれば良い感じに立ち上がってくれるようになる、というのが Docker Compose の便利な点のひとつです。

また、チーム開発とは直接的には関係しづらいでしょう。チームの開発者ひとりひとりが使っている環境をなるべく揃えたいといった文脈で選べるツールのひとつではありますが、チーム開発に必要・不要と断言できるモノではないです。

より詳しくは公式のドキュメントを読んでみてください: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: あ。ではもしGithubでクローンしたリポジトリにDocker composeしかなくてもこれは開発するアプリケーションの作動や使用に特に関係ない感じなんですか？

Comment: README の動作方法のところに Docker Compose が書かれているってことですかね？　原理的には `docker run` で代替できるはずなので Docker Compose がなくても動かせるはずではあります。ただ設定ファイルが元から準備されているのであればわざわざ使わない選択肢を選ぶメリットは小さいかなと思います。

Comment: そうするとターミナルではdocker run
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Create and run a new container from an imageと出てきます。これどうやって引数を入れればいいですか？

Comment: `docker run` に何も引数を与えなければ当然そうなります……。詳しくは Docker CLI のマニュアルをご覧ください。また、`docker compose` を使わずに動かす部分については元の質問の範囲から外れてきているので別の質問としてご投稿ください。繰り返しになりますが `docker compose` を使うのがオススメです。

Comment: この引数はリポジトリのどこ書かれてますか？READMEとかですか？

Comment: 元の質問の範囲から外れてきているので別の質問としてご投稿ください。

Comment: そうですね。すみません。